# How can i add new row to datatable based on button click in primefaces?

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Hi i am very new to `primefaces`. I Tried the following functionality.

I add a button to `primefaces` datatable as a `column`.

Based on the `button` I add new row to same data `table`.

For this i use the following `code`.

### in vendorcontacts.xhtml

```
    <p:dataTable id="dt" var="pmr" value="#{globalMaster.vendorContactsList}"
                                    style="width:900px;">
                                    <p:column headerText="Organisation">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{pmr.contactSno}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Program">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{pmr.location}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column headerText="Action" >
                                       <p:commandButton value="Add New" action="#{globalMaster.getVendorContactsList}"  />
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>
```

### And my Bean code is:

```
public List<VendorContactDetails> getVendorContactsList(){
    try{
        VendorContactDetails veneContactDetails=new VendorContactDetails();
        vendorConList.add(veneContactDetails);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }return vendorConList;
}
```

And now the problem is;

Intially my view page displays single row.

When i click the add new button my view page displays 3 rows instead of second row.

I find something in debug mode my list method calls `no.of times(i.e no.of properties in my modal class i.e VendorContactDetails)`

I change my bean scope session to view scope .but no use.

Is there any mistake in my code.Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, view scope is correct, but;

`getVendorContactsList()` should just initialize the list if needed, and return it.

```
public List<VendorContactDetails> getVendorContactsList(){
    if (vendorConList == null)
    {
        vendorConList = new ArrayList<VendorContactDetails>();
    }
    return vendorConList;
}
```

then, there should be a separate method to add an item to the list.

```
public void addVendorContactToList(){
    getVendorContactsList().add(new VendorContactDetails());
}
```

and at last, the button adding a new item should not be in a table column. it's not an operation related to an existing item/row.

```
<p:commandButton value="Add New" process="@this" update="dt"
    action="#{globalMaster.addVendorContactToList}"/>
```

if you are planning to update or delete an item in list, then those buttons will be in table columns.